# How to colour long sentences without causing them to overflow and exceed the page?

Tags: support, mathjax, markdown, formatting

The entitled question can be seen in an older version [How can a Fields Medallist be 'not very good at logic'?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2116634/53259):

> $\color{green}{\qquad \text{Well, the idea that mathematics is synonymous with logic is a great ridiculous statement that some people make. Mathematics is very difficult to define, actually, what constitutes mathematics. Logical thinking is a key part of mathematics, but it's by no means the only part.}}$  You've got to have a lot of input and material from somewhere, you've got to have ideas coming from physics, concepts from geometry. You've got to have imagination, you're going to use intuition, guesswork, vision, like a creative artist has. In fact, proofs are usually only the last bit of the story, when you come to tie up the... dot the i's and cross the T's. Sometimes the proof is needed to hold the whole thing together like the steel structure of a building, but sometimes you've stopped putting it together, and the proof is just the last little bit of polish on the surface.
>     $\color{green}{\qquad \text{So the most time mathematicians are working, they're concerned with much more than proofs, they're concerned with ideas, understanding why this is true, what leads where, possible links. You play around in your mind with a whole host of ill-defined things.}}$

Colour may be needed, especially if the two formatting methods of bold and bold + italics are already used.

Comment: Is there any reason to not just use bold and italics? Color is bad for a lot of reasons, not the least of which is that some people are colorblind.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, because the title (per the original website) is already bolded; so I wish a distinct format.

Comment: Colour is **not** needed. It is extremely rare that using colour is a good idea.

Comment: The title is not just bolded, it is a headline font size. Bolder is fine here.

Comment: In any event, given the question's presentation right now, it is impossible to read the specific text you want the reader to read. So you necessarily need to find another way to format this for it to be a useful question, and there are plenty of ways to do so that don't discriminate against the colorblind and which can be read by humans.

Answer (score 14):

Simple solution: don't abuse MathJax to colour your text.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Isn't HTML supposed to work? I tried the html tag span style="color:green", as detailed [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Font-Color-Tags-in-HTML), but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Thanks; you are correct that 'This doesn't really answer the question.'

Comment: @DustanLevenstein SE only allows a very small subset of HTML tags, which are listed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777). (This information is linked to from the "Help" in the question/answer input boxes.)

Comment: That seems surprisingly limited. So I guess the answer for OP should be to use bold or italics, or <em>.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Markdown should be used. It allows four levels (i.e. three increments) of emphasis for text (not including headlines). I think  this usually is plenty enough.

Answer (score 2):

I hesitate to suggest this, but if you  *really* ***really*** need to do this, you could put just one word per pair of `$...$`, so that your browser can render a line break anywhere it wants.